# Creating a valid JSON file from pulled data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

In a bit of downtime from work I decided to mess around with data scraping and JSON just for a bit of fun. So I set up a dummy page on my site which changes a song name and artist every x minutes and created a scraper to pull off the page and write to a JSON file. So far so good. My script is pulling the data from the page when it should and writing it to a JSON file but its coming back invalid. What I am getting is this

```
{
    "trackName": "Feels So Close",
    "artistTitle": "Calvin Harris",
    "playTime": "9:24"
}{
    "trackName": "",
    "artistTitle": "Studio B",
    "playTime": "9:28"
}
```

And what I want is more like this

```
{
    "response1": {
        "trackName": "Feels So Close",
        "artistTitle": "Calvin Harris",
        "playTime": "9:24"
    },
    "response2": {
        "trackName": "",
        "artistTitle": "Studio B",
        "playTime": "9:28"
    }
}
```

This is the js that pulls the data:

```
  request("mySite", function(error, response, body) {
    if(error) {
      console.log("Error: " + error);
    }

    console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);

    var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    $('.track').each(function(index){
      var json = { trackName: "", artistTitle: "", playTime: ""};

      var title = $(this).find(".track a").text().trim();
      var artist = $(this).find(".artist").text().trim();
      var hours = new Date().getHours();
      var mins = new Date().getMinutes();

      json.trackName = title;
      json.artistTitle = artist;    
      json.playTime = hours + ":" + mins;

      fs.appendFileSync('trackList.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(error){
        if(error) {
          console.log('Error: ' + error);
        };
      });
    });
  });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I have been looking for a solution, but seeing as I don't really know what to be looking for I came here for a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an empty object to then use `.each()` iterate the DOM element and create desired properties i.e. `response1, response2`.

The finally use `.appendFileSync()` to send data once after iteration.

```
//Create empty object
var json = {};   

//Iterate to create complete JSON object
$('.track').each(function(i){
    var title = $(this).find(".track a").text().trim();
    var artist = $(this).find(".artist").text().trim();
    var hours = new Date().getHours();
    var mins = new Date().getMinutes();

    //Create property object
    json['response' + i] = {
        trackName : title;
        artistTitle : artist;    
        playTime : hours + ":" + mins;
    };
});

//Then send it to update
fs.appendFileSync('trackList.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(error){
    if(error) {
      console.log('Error: ' + error);
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Satpal, just made a quick change to it that made it work on my end :)

Comment: @Damien, There was typo on my part edited the answer